# how to write GameObject position in the Scene to json file?

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

on Clicking the button, I m loading the function WriteJsonForLevel(). I have placed three GameObject with the tag name "RedCoin" and I want to write the position of the GameObject to a JSON file. I can get the position of the object, but it's all overwritten. I can only see the last GameObject position (i.e the completion of the loop)
[image]

```
public List<GameObject> levelObjects;
 public string level;
 public Vector3 pos;
 // Start is called before the first frame update
 void Start()
 {
     levelObjects = new List<GameObject>();
     
 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     
 }
 public void WritejsonForAll()
 {
     WriteJsonForLevel();
 }
 public void WriteJsonForLevel()
 {
  
    /* FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/sample.json",FileMode.Create);
     StreamWriter writer= new StreamWriter(fs);*/
     GameObject[] coinObjRed = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RedCoin");
     putAllObjectInList(coinObjRed);
   
     
   
     
 }
 public void putAllObjectInList(GameObject[] p)
 {
     string path = Application.dataPath + "/text.json";
    foreach (GameObject q in p)
     {
         levelObjects.Add(q);
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < levelObjects.Count; i++)
     {
         GameObject lvlObj = levelObjects[i];
         Vector3 pos = lvlObj.transform.position;
         string posOutput = JsonUtility.ToJson(pos);
          File.WriteAllText(path,posOutput);
          Debug.Log("position:" + posOutput);
 
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `WriteAllText` which will [overwrite the file every time it is called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-5.0). As it is overwriting each time it is in the loop, it will only write the last object to the file as every other previous write is overwritten. I would consider making a serialized class of data, assigning the data to it, converting it to a JSON string then saving that.

```
// stores individual locations for saving
[System.Serializable]
public class IndividualLocation
{
    public IndividualLocation(Vector3 pos)
    {
        xPos = pos.x;
        yPos = pos.y;
        zPos = pos.z;
    }
    
    public float xPos;
    public float yPos;
    public float zPos;
}

// stores all game locations for saving
[System.Serializable]
public class AllGameLocations
{
    public List<IndividualLocation> Locations = new List<IndividualLocation>();
}

public void PutAllObjectInList(in GameObject[] p)
{ 
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/text.json";

    // create a new object to write to
    AllGameLocations data = new AllGameLocations();
    
    // iterate the objects adding each to our structure
    foreach(GameObject obj in p)
    {
        data.Locations.Add(new IndividualLocation(obj.transform.position));
    }
    
    // now that the data is filled, write out to the file
    File.WriteAllText(path, JsonUtility.ToJson(AllGameLocations));
}
```

If you need a snippet on how to load the data properly I can add one.

Edit: Here is a load snippet

```
public void LoadJSONObject()
{
    string path = Application.dataPath + "/text.json"; 
    
    // if the file path or name does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)))
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("File or path does not exist! " + path);
        return
    }

    // load in the save data as byte array
    byte[] jsonDataAsBytes = null;

    try
    {
        jsonDataAsBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        Debug.Log("<color=green>Loaded all data from: </color>" + path);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed to load data from: " + path);
        Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
        return;
    }

    if (jsonDataAsBytes == null)
        return;

    // convert the byte array to json
    string jsonData;

    // convert the byte array to json
    jsonData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(jsonDataAsBytes);

    // convert to the specified object type
    AllGameLocations returnedData;
    
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite<AllGameLocations>(jsonData, AllGameLocations);
    
    // use returnedData as a normal object now
    float firstObjectX = returnedData.Locations[0].xPos;
    }
}
```

Let me know if the Load works, just typed it up untested. Added some error handling as well to assure data exists and the load properly works.

Comment: wow....its working.I'm newbie .Thank you .Please provide the snippet to load the data property as well and one more thing , Is this the right way to do LevelEditor ?

Comment: @Kathiravan No worries everyone's gotta start somewhere. I can add a new snippet for a load. I am a bit confused by your question. What do you mean by `LevelEditor`?

Comment: @Kathiravan Added a load snippet. Let me know if it works for you, there could be bugs as it is untested on my end.

Comment: Sure will check load snippet and update you. Actually I want to create a code such that , when I a button is clicked all the gameObject arranged by the designer in the scene view should be updated in the json format.(their positions, properties...) so that a developer loads the json and display the object as designed for various level .This is what I was taught.This is one they called it as levelediotr .I'm I correct.. For every level designer designs the level from prefabs and clicks the button

Comment: Gotcha so you're making a level editor tool and serializing object positions. There is not real wrong or right back to go about it. It's all really opinion and depends heavily on your use case and a lot of other factors. For simple levels with a few moving parts this would work, yes.

Comment: Thank you.just want to create some portfolio and want to become a Unity Game developer.For one gameObject the above code you suggested work , if I'm going to add some more objects what I should do..

Comment: There are many ways to do this. One approach for a full tool, I would constrain the objects my designer could use. Give them a list of objects they can generate so I can serialize each one with an id. When they generate an object I would add it to a list of that object. When they click save, I can keep different sublists of each unique object. I can then load each object by id and then find the specific details such as position, rotation, etc. by index when spawning them.

Comment: Will try.Thank you.

Comment: @Kathiravan Found a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34736DHWzaI&ab_channel=TurboMakesGames) that is a decent jumping-off point. Instead of how he sets it up, I would make a tool that allows a user to select from a pre-determined list of objects. Something like [this](https://imgur.com/a/g6gxZzD) which is a custom editor for spawning track pieces. Select an object, hit spawn and you know where it exists, what it is, etc.